# Объединение таблицы CTE с запросом в SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
WITH ParentCTE (ID, NAME)
    AS 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Торговое наименование]) AS ID,
                [Торговое наименование] AS NAME
        FROM [Test].[dbo].[Nomenclature]
        GROUP BY [Торговое наименование]
    )
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Торговое наименование]) AS ID,
    [Торговое наименование] AS NAME,
    [Наименование товара на этикетке] AS Name_of_sec_pack,
    GTIN,
    (SELECT ID FROM ParentCTE WHERE ParentCTE.NAME = Nomenclature.[Торговое наименование]) AS PARENT_ID
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Nomenclature]
```

Результат запроса:

```
| ID  | NAME      | Name_of_sec_pack              | GTIN | PARENT_ID  |
| --- | --------- | ----------------------------- | ---- | ---------- |
| 1   | Амлодипин | таблетки "амлодипин" по 25 мг | 1111 | 1          |
| 2   | Амлодипин | таблетки "амлодипин" по 50 мг | 1120 | 1          |
| 3   | Анальгин  | Анальгин таблетки 300 мг №10  | 1148 | 2          |
| ... | ...       | ...                           | ...  | ...        |
```

ParentCTE:

```
| ID  | NAME       |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | Амлодипин  |
| 2   | Анальгин   |
| ... | ...        |
```

**Вопрос:**
Как объединить их, чтобы было вот так?

```
| ID  | NAME      | Name_of_sec_pack              | GTIN | PARENT_ID  |
| --- | --------- | ----------------------------- | ---- | ---------- |
| 1   | Амлодипин |                               |      |            |
| 2   | Амлодипин | таблетки "амлодипин" по 25 мг | 1111 | 1          |
| 3   | Амлодипин | таблетки "амлодипин" по 50 мг | 1120 | 1          |
| 4   | Анальгин  |                               |      |            |
| 5   | Анальгин  | Анальгин таблетки 300 мг №10  | 1148 | 4          |
| ... | ...       | ...                           | ...  | ...        |
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)
Nov 1 2020 00:48:37
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 (Build 9200: )
(Hypervisor)

**UPDATE:**
CREATE TABLE

```
USE [Test]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nomenclature](
    [GTIN] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Торговое наименование] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Наименование товара на этикетке] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

INSERT INTO

```
USE [Test]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Nomenclature]
           ([GTIN]
           ,[Торговое наименование]
           ,[Наименование товара на этикетке])
     VALUES
           ('1111', 'Амлодипин', 'таблетки "амлодипин" по 25 мг'),
           ('1120', 'Амлодипин', 'таблетки "амлодипин" по 50 мг'),
           ('1148', 'Анальгин', 'Анальгин таблетки 300 мг №10')
GO
```

Comment: Выложите пример исходных данных в виде CREATE TABLE +INSERT INTO, и покажите нужный ответ для именно этих данных. Без этих ваших многоточий...

Comment: @Akina, добавил CREATE TABLE и INSERT INTO. Нужный ответ в вопросе. Должна получиться иерархия по `[Торговое наименование]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, NULL PARENT_ID
    FROM Nomenclature
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT NULL, [Торговое наименование], NULL, NULL
    FROM Nomenclature
),
cte2 AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Торговое наименование], [Наименование товара на этикетке]) ID,
           [Торговое наименование],
           [Наименование товара на этикетке],
           [GTIN]
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.[Торговое наименование] NAME,
       t1.[Наименование товара на этикетке] Name_of_sec_pack,
       t1.GTIN,
       CASE WHEN t1.[GTIN] IS NOT NULL
            THEN t2.ID
            END PARENT_ID
FROM cte2 t1
JOIN cte2 t2 ON t1.[Торговое наименование] = t2.[Торговое наименование]
            AND t2.[GTIN] IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.ID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d0dda15cafb48b179db1b3619755b009

PS. Оптимизировать - лень.